# Can't Create Nexus 7 AVD

Tags: android, android-virtual-device

I am trying to create a Nexus 7 AVD. Regardless of the choices I make, I can not seem to actually create it since the OK button is greyed out.

The Choices I made:

```
AVD Name: Nexus7AVD
Device: Nexus 7
Target: Android 4.2 - API Level 17
Keyboard: Not present
Skin: Display
Front Camera: Emulated
Memory: RAM 1024, VM Heap: 32
Internal Storage: 200 MiB
SD Card: No selection
Emulation Options: Use Host GPU
```

What is wrong with the choices I made?

Thanks
Eric

Comment: Can you do it via command line?

Comment: I did not and when I tried, it would not work. However, it did give me an error! :)  armeabi is not installed... so, installing that now. Hope it works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look at my picture, this worked for me.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I think you don't have system image installed in your IDE. Install System image by selecting Android SDK manager option and checked the system images for the targeted device you want.

Answer (score 0):

You need the following:

AVD name - must exist and mustn't have any spaces (which is dumb cos you cant have 'Nexus 7')

Device

Target - API level, which you must have installed via Android SDK Manager

CPU/ABI - again needs to be installed via SDK manager (under your chosen API level you will have various system images eg ARM EABI v7a System image - these relate to CPU types. You need to install the one chosen i the dropdown, though I think if its not installed you dont get the option)

Skin - needed (choose WSVGA as the simplest, I think - but havent experimented with this)

The rest is optional I think. Have heard a suggestion that SDcard should be 'binary multiples' - eg 256, 1024 etc, but havent verified that (just added that as FYI - isnt needed to get the OK button visible).

With all that the OK button should be clickable.